# Submit form and close window

Tags: javascript, html, forms, window

I can't understand why this isn't working.

I have a form opened in new tab, which I want to close when submitting:

```
<form name="form" id="form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    //form inputs
    <button accesskey="C" class="boton" onclick="form.submit(); alert('waiting...'); window.close()"> <u>A</u>djuntar</button>

 </form>
```

when I remove window.close() the form is submitted, but when it's in my code, it shows the alert but not submitting.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Are you opening the window with JS? I don't believe you can close just any old window, it has to be one you created (As a security measure) Also, I'm not sure if you can close tabs with JS *at-all* anymore, though `.close()` did used to work

Comment: Button may close only the windows that were opened by it. Refer `https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/close`

Comment: try with onclick="form.submit(); alert('waiting...'); window.close();"

Comment: @KinjalGohil — That's the code that already appears in the question

Comment: Calling `form.submit()` when a submit button is clicked is redundant (submit buttons trigger form submissions anyway).

Comment: @Quentin I put semicolon. Sometimes it will also create issue.

Comment: @KinjalGohil — Adding a semicolon after the last statement in a script will never make any difference in JavaScript.

Comment: I had a similar situation with a Mailchimp form. Not identical because I used a modal for the form. I wanted to hide the modal on submit in case the user wanted to come back to the tab after being redirected to the Mailchimp reg confirmation page in a new tab.

The function to close the modal was preventing the submit and redirect from happening. But when I used setTimeout to delay the modal getting closed by 1s, everything worked fine.
This may work in the case of closing the tab itself?

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to open the form in a new window (or tab).
you can either submit the data in ajax or use an inner hidden iframe as the target property of the form element. this way the form will open in a hidden inner element. e.g.:

```
<form id="eFrm" target="ifrm1">
</form>
<iframe id="ifrm1" name="ifrm1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form won't be submitted until the event handler function has finished running.

`alert` blocks all execution of everything until the dialog is dismissed.

`close` closes a the window, so there is nowhere to load the form submission into, which cancels the request.

---

If you are going to close a window, don't expect it to be able to send an HTTP request at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found a solution, but I am posting this anyway for anybody who comes across the same in the future.

I am using Java servlets, but I think that is the same with every form submission => ability to choose which page must be displayed after the posted data was processed.

Once I have submitted the form, the doPost method in the servlet allows me to say which URL I want the browser to display after the data has been processed.

So, you can do probably do something along these lines:

```
   request.getRequestDispatcher ( "/ClosePopup.html" ).forward ( request, response );
```

Then also create a file called ClosePopup.html, with nothing but a close () instruction

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body onLoad = "window.close();">
    </body>
</html>
```

This way it won't be the button you click to trigger the closure of the popup, but you will be loading a self destroying page after the form is submitted. The final result is identical.

Comment: For the person who downvoted it : what went wrong? It works for me, but if you don't get the same result then maybe I can think of a solution which can be applied to more cases, based on what I posted